# как закрыть окно командного файла.bat после окончания всех циклов?

Tags: bat

:: У меня командный файл.bat отлично выполняет свои задачи но по окончанию циклов хотелось-бы чтобы он закрылся сам а этого не происходит. Как сделать чтоб по окончании циклов окно файла.bat закрылось само ?
:: _________________

```
@echo off

set counter=0

:loop

if %counter% equ 15 goto :EOF

set /a counter+=1

echo %counter%

goto loop

rem Выше код для выполнения команды цикла только 15 раза - equ 15

 :loop

@echo off

title 1_firefox_15x3850

SET processMozila="firefox_1.exe"

SET pathToFirefox=ะก:\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox\

taskkill.exe /F /IM %processMozila%

timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK

START C:\Users\OlehNITRO5\Desktop\BRAUSERS_Register_111.11.11.11\BitcoinAuto_May_IP_***.**.**.***\Firefox\FirefoxPortable.exe -no-remote -profile ะก:\profile imacros://run/?m=May_skripts\Multibot.js

TIMEOUT /T 3850 /NOBREAK

rem  ниже команды - закрывает bat файл где title 1_firefox_aztecafaucetTRON

taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq 1_firefox_aztecafaucetTRON"

rem  ниже команды - ЗАКОНЧИЛИ ЦИКЛ ЗАКРЫВАЕМ firefox_1.exe
  
@echo off

title 1_firefox_15x3850

SET processMozila="firefox_1.exe"

SET pathToFirefox=ะก:\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox\

taskkill.exe /F /IM %processMozila%

timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK

rem  выше команды - ЗАКОНЧИЛИ ЦИКЛЫ ЗАКРЫВАЕМ firefox_1.exe 

goto loop

exit
```

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov  Я сделал как Вы советовали "В конце файла.bat напиште exit 1" и все-равно окно командного .bat файла не закрывается по окончании циклов. Сам браузер закрывается, работа проделана а окно командного .bat файла остается открытым на экране или опущенно на панель инструментов но не закрывается.

Comment: Судя по коду, у Вас не прописан выход из цикла -единственная команла, которая могла бы его прервать  `taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq..` Но из кода это не очевидно.

Answer (score 1):

В конце файла.bat напиште exit 1, вместо exit.